# List all elements of $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/\langle x^2+3x+1\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

> List all elements of $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/\langle x^2+3x+1\rangle$

Is there a simple way to solve these kind of questions (only using pen and paper)?

If I understand it correctly, I can multiply each element of $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ with each other and replace all $x^2$ with $2x+4$, then $x^3$ with $4x^2+x+1$, etc.

But there are way too many elements in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$. Is there an easier way?

Comment: In the future, use \langle and \rangle for brackets like $\langle$ and $\rangle$. It looks better this way.

Comment: Interpreting $\mathbf{Z}_5$ as $\mathbf{Z}/5$, then note that it is a finite field $\mathbf{F}_5$. Therefore, if $x^2+3x+1$ is irreducible, then it will generate a degree 2 extension.

Comment: @Prospect Is there some difference in writing it as $\mathbb{Z}_5 / \langle p(x) \rangle$, $(\mathbb{Z} / \langle 5 \rangle) / \langle p(x) \rangle$, $(\mathbb{Z} / 5 \mathbb{Z}) / \langle p(x) \rangle$? Can I assume that elements of all these three rings are equal (or at least isomorphic)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, note that all elements of $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ of the form $px+q$ with $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}_5$ are different when considered modulo $x^2+3x+1$ (their difference is only a multiple of $x^2+3x+1$ when they are equal).

Now let $ax^2+bx+c\in \mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ be a quadratic polynomial. Then:
$$
ax^2+bx+c-a(x^2+3x+1)=(b-3a)x+(c-a)
$$
So we see that:
$$ax^2+bx+c\equiv (b-3a)x+(c-a)\mod x^2+3x+1$$
Hence all quadratic polynomials are equivalent to some polynomial of the form $px+q$.

We can inductively reduce the degree of any polynomial of degree $\geq 2$ modulo $x^2+3x+1$ in this way:
$$
(a_n x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0)-a_nx^{n-2}(x^2+3x+1)=(a_{n-1}-3a_n)x^{n-1}+\cdots
$$
So:
$$
(a_n x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0)\equiv (a_{n-1}-3a_n)x^{n-1}+\cdots\mod x^2+3x+1
$$
Therefore we find that any element of $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ is (modulo $x^2+3x+1$) equivalent to a "linear" polynomial. The elements of $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/\langle x^2+3x+1\rangle$ are therefore precisely the equivalence classes of the polynomials of the form $px+q$ with $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}_5$. Since $\mathbb{Z}_5$ has $5$ elements, there are $5\cdot 5=25$ such polynomials.

We did not really use a special property of $x^2+3x+1$ or $\mathbb{Z}_5$ here. In general, when we have a finite finite $F$ with $n$ elements, and a polynomial $P$ of degree $d$ in $F[x]$, then the ring (field iff $P$ is irreducible) $F[x]/\langle P\rangle$ will have $n^d$ elements (you can try to construct the argument in a general case for yourself, you will need that each nonzero element of $F$ has a multiplicative inverse).

Comment: All fine, except that $F[x]/\langle P\rangle$ may not be a field. It isn't in this example.

Comment: @lhf Yes indeed, thanks.

Comment: So in fact, if we put there any irreducible polynomial $p(x)$ of degree 2, then the $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle$ will still be the same 25 elements? Am I right?

Comment: @dash $p(x)$ does not necessarily need to be irreducible, this is only to guarantee that the resulting ring $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is in fact a field. In your example, $x^2+3x+1=(x-1)^2$ (modulo $5$) so the polynomial is in fact not irreducible. For any polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $2$, $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ has $25$ elements, namely the equivalence classes of the "linear" polynomials. However, for different $p(x)$ these equivalence classes are different. The representatives are the same, but the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ are not.

Comment: You said that the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/\langle x^2+3x+1\rangle$ are precisely $px+q$ where $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}_5$. But now I'm confused, could you give me an example of a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree 2, where there will be different 25 elements of $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle$?

Comment: @dash The set $S:=\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ consists of equivalence classes modulo the relation $f(x)\;R\;g(x)\iff f(x)-g(x)=h(x)p(x)$ for some $h(x)\in\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$. That is, the elements of $S$ are of the form $\{f(x),f(x)+p(x),f(x)+2p(x),\cdots,f(x)+xp(x),\cdots\}$. We can represent each equivalence class by one element in it. For any polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $2$, the "linear" polynomials are representatives of different equivalence classes. However, the equivalence classes themselves are different for different $p(x)$.

Comment: @dash For example, when we consider the polynomial $q(x)=x^2+x+1$, then when we multiply $x-1$ with itself modulo $q(x)$ we get: $$ (x-1)^2\equiv x^2+3x+1\equiv 2x+1\mod q(x)$$, whereas $$(x-1)^2\equiv 0\mod x^2+3x+1$$ When we consider $x-1$ as representative for an element of $\mathbb{Z}_5/\langle q(x)\rangle$, the multiplicative structure will be different. Therefore we cannot say that $[x-1]$ is the "same element" in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ for different $p(x)$.

Comment: Then, can I say for any $p(x)$ of degree 2 that $\mathbb{Z}_5/\langle p(x) \rangle = \{ax+b+\langle p(x) \rangle \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_5\} = \{\{ax+b+np(x) \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\} \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_5\}$. Do I understand it correctly now?

Comment: @dash Yes, except for the second equality; $\langle p(x)\rangle =p(x)\:\mathbb{Z}_5[x]=\{p(x)h(x)\mid h(x)\in \mathbb{Z}_5[x]\}$. So if you replace the $\mathbb{N}$ with $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ this is correct.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/\langle x^2+3x+1\rangle$ is the set of classes of polynomials mod $x^2+3x+1$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

By the Euclidean division of polynomials, each element has a canonical representative of the form $ax+b$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}_5$.

Therefore, the ring has $5\times 5=25$ elements.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\Bbb{Z}_5$ is a finite field. $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/\langle x^2+3x+1\rangle$ is a vector space of finite dimension over that field. If you are being asked this question, you should know how to calculate the number of elements in the field and the dimension of the vector space. That should cut down "way too many" to A to Z with one letter spare.